# Difference between TaggedDocument and TaggedLineDocument in gensim? and How to work with files in a directory?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, text-classification, doc2vec

I am new to doc2vec and I wish to classify set of texts using it.

I am confused about TaggedDocument and TaggedLineDocument.

1) What is the difference between two? Is it that TaggedLineDocument is collection of TaggedDocuments?

2) If I have a directory containing all the files, How to generate feature vectors for them? Should I create a new file where each line contains text from the file from the directory?

Comment: better ask two separate questions and link them if necessary. "How to work with files in a directory?" says nothong about what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

`TaggedDocument` is an illustrative class to represent objects that `Doc2Vec` can take as text examples. You don't need to use it – you just need to provide objects that have a `words` property that is a list of string tokens, and a `tags` property that's a list of tags to be associated with the document. (That is, you can provide your text examples as an object that is 'shaped' or 'duck-typed' like `TaggedDocument`.)

`TaggedLineDocument` is a utility class for taking a file that has one document per line, whose token-wordss are already whitespace-delimited, and turning it into an iterable collection of `TaggedDocument`s, where each doc has as its only tag its integer line-number. As such, it's a minimal example of streaming texts to `Doc2Vec`, for the common-case of a single doc-per-line text file as input, and no need for custom per-doc tags/IDs.

If your data is in other formats, you can't use `TaggedLineDocument` directly, but it might be a useful starting point. If you're OK with simple tags numbered from 0 to the count of documents, you could transform your format to the single file `TaggedLineDocument` expects.

Alternatively, and especially if you need to use custom tags, you'd write your own class that turns your data source – whether it's a set of files or an network resource or a database – into an iterable object which emits one `TaggedDocument`-like object for each example.